# How to automatically set path and filename of sap .xlsx/.xls/.xlsm extraction with SAP GUI

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm using a SAP GUI Script to make an extraction of a SAP transaction, but the scripts stops because of the save form

[image: Save Form SAP]

I have to write the filename and saving path manually, **How can i do to let SAP do this automatically?**

Code:

```
Public Sub RunGUIScript_PROJ_WP_INFO_INV()

Dim W_Ret As Boolean
Dim answer As Integer


' Connect to SAP
W_Ret = Attach_Session
If Not W_Ret Then
Exit Sub
End If


On Error GoTo myerr

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGD-MAX_LINES").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGD-MAX_LINES").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/btnPUSH[4,1]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/btnPUSH[4,1]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"

WaitingForm.Show
MsgBox "Extracción Exitosa", vbInformation, "SAP"

Exit Sub
myerr:
  MsgBox "Error while retrieving data", vbOKOnly + vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Maqybe [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/) helps

Comment: Another way could be this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779126/how-to-vba-wait-for-windows-save-dialogbox-and-sendkeys)

Comment: I activated that option but when I recording the macro, sap didn't record the replacement of the path and filename, idk how to do that.

Comment: I think you need to deactivate the option and then the sapgui recording should give you what you are after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save PDF from SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301299/save-pdf-from-sap)

Comment: @Storax which option ?

Comment: Option _Show native  MS windows dialogs_ should be deactivated. If this does not help you may try the second link I provided.

Comment: Oh i didn't see it, y put your code before the SaveAs Dialog box but i receive this [error](https://imgur.com/a/Z7uZ9AZ)

Comment: How should I know without knowing the code you are actually using.

Comment: Before `session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"` 

I added the code of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779126/how-to-vba-wait-for-windows-save-dialogbox-and-sendkeys) you send me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our SAP recently updated and broke many of my scripts, disabling the "show native MS Windows dialogs" allowed my previous code to run again.  A basic SAP script cannot directly inteface with the MS windows dialog box shown in your screen shot.

below is the code to set the path and file name

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

'set path and file name
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "\\network\path\to\folder\"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "Filename.xlsx"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
```